# Line $GH$ makes an angle of $\pi/6$ with the $Y$ axis. Determine the gradient of Line $GH$

Tags: trigonometry

Ok, well using simple geometry I can work out that this is a line that makes a $60°$ angle with the $x$-axis.

But I am used to working with points to solve gradient problems and using rise over run with the difference of $x$ and $y$.
Using unit circle I know the sin and cos of a $60°$ angle

Basically that is all I know. 
Can you help me step by step on solving this. 
I dont need the answer per se, I need to understand how to work out the problem.

Thank you

Comment: Make a right-triangle where one side is horizontal, one is vertical, and the hypotenuse is along the line. Relate rise/run to a trig function of an angle in that triangle.

Comment: Hi @Melissa, is everything alright now?

Comment: Not really, I am glad i have the answer, but I am confused about this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/273361/calculating-the-gradient-of-a-line-with-only-the-angle-of-the-y-axis

Why is the answer not just the tan15? Why is the x and y turned upside down?

Why is the calc give not how i was explained to do it. surely they are the same thing?

Comment: Hi Melissa, I'm glad you asked that question! Mathematics is not about blindly following a formula which you were threatening to do there. Try drawing the triangle for the picture in the other question and use what you have learnt here. You first have to work out the angle (Can you see that it is $75^{\circ}$? Ignore the answer first.) Then using $\tan$, work out the rise over run. You will then notice that the gradient is "running" in the wrong direction, so you need to compensate for that by taking negatives.

Comment: Thank you BlackAdder for hanging in there. Ok, I still want to turn the thing in the right way and see tan 15, but I can surmise you got 75 from subtracting 15 from 90. I don't know where to drop the line to form a triangle, although i do know you want me to find a triangle so i can use tan to find slope. I can find tan of 75 by adding together tan30 = √3/3 and tan45 = 1 so therefore tan 75 = 3+√3 BUT I STILL DONT KNOW WHY I NEEDED TO USE 75 OR HOW TO FIND THE TRIANGLE? I DO SEE THAT the slope could be negative if i pretend I am looking at a normal x y

Comment: So 15 normal is -75. kind of like looking at the unit circle and saying 15 is the same as -345? teach me how to see this as y x messed up please. I cant get past the need to cock my head to the left and see it normally! And please dont give up on me yet, my test is wednesday or thursday and i need to pass it! Your time is not wasted on me!

Comment: @BlackAdder please.

Comment: I'm so sorry for leaving you hanging. Firstly, $\tan 75^{\circ}$ is not $3+\sqrt{3}$, it's $2+\sqrt{3}$. Now that we know what the tangent of the angle is, we need to picture the line. Draw the diagram; it really does not matter which side you pick. But if you pick the side on the negative $x$-axis, you must drop a line from the original line onto the $x$-axis. Now, we have a triangle formed from the original line, the line we dropped and the $x$-axis, and the tangent of $75^{\circ}$. So, we can conclude that the gradient is $-2-\sqrt{3}$. Hope that helped. I'm glad you are making the effort.

Answer (score 0):

The line is going to make a $60^{\circ}$ with the $x$-axis (assuming angle is measured anti-clockwise from the positive $x$-axis) as you said.

So what would $\tan60^{\circ}$ tell us about the rise over the run of the line?

Hint: $$\tan=\frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}}$$

Edit: Since $$\tan 60^{\circ}=\sqrt{3}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{1},$$

the rise is therefore $\sqrt{3}$ and the run is $1$, hence the gradient is $\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: I did this...tan of 60° is (1/2, √3/2)
So, √3/2 divided by 1/2 is equal to the same as √3/2 multiplied by reciprocal or 2 which gives final answer of √3

Is that the gradient? Am I done?

Comment: I am confused then about this post WHERE IS THAT ONE MINUS THING, AND WHAT IS IT?
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/273361/calculating-the-gradient-of-a-line-with-only-the-angle-of-the-y-axis

Comment: @Melissa Your first comment is right. Well done! :)

Comment: @BlackAdder It could also be an angle of $120^\circ$ to the $x$-axis, if the angle is measured anticlockwise from the $y$-axis.

Comment: @Daryl That is true! I've added a line to reflect that observation. Cheers!